# How to use ogr2ogr to only add new features to an existing layer?

Tags: ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

It seems like the correct usage is as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -lco SCHEMA=mySchema -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=myServer;database=myDb;trusted_connection=yes;" "myShapeFile.shp"
```

But it is attempting to create a new layer, as if I didn't set the -update and -append flags:

```
ERROR 1: Layer Addresses already exists, CreateLayer failed.
Use the layer creation option OVERWRITE=YES to replace it.
```

What is the proper way to *-append* newly created items?  I'm fine with updating the database with any detected changes to the shapefile if the tool allows it (*-update*).

Comment: -lco stands for layer creation option and usually they can't be used together with -append and -update. However, I do not know mssql driver and how to define the alternative schema in some other way.

Comment: Directly from the documentation!

SCHEMA: Set name of schema for new table. Using the same layer name in different schemas is supported, but not in the public schema and others. Note that using the -overwrite option of ogr2ogr and -lco SCHEMA= option at the same time will not work, as the ogr2ogr utility will not understand that the existing layer must be destroyed in the specified schema. Use the -nln option of ogr2ogr instead, or better the active_schema connection string. See below example.